# X-UA-Compatible in JavaScript and CSS files

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8

For IE8 compatibility, we have added the `X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE7` header to the IIS response headers list.

For some reason these headers are being sent down for ASPX etc, but not for static files - JS/CSS.

Does this header have any relevance for JS/CSS content which gets linked into HTML content? My guess is that as long as the HTML received has this response header along with it, IE8 should respect this header and display the content based on EmulateIE7 compatibility mode. Is that the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this header have any relevance for JS/CSS content which gets linked into HTML content?

no, you just have to send the header with the HTML file. The browser than switches to backward compatibility mode and treats all linked resources "the ie7 way".

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered updating the code to standards and then applying IE7 fixes like [IE8-js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/)? Putting that header in is just saying "this site is broken by design" which won't help you with other browsers or future versions of IE.